# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape specific element within a CSS class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup in Python to scrape the 3rd li element within a CSS class. That said, i'm pretty new to this, and am not sure the best way to go about this.

Within the below example, what i'm trying to do is to scrape the 170 votes from this list (**in the real world example there are hundreds of these on a page that i'm looking to scrape, but they're all nested under the same CSS class within the 3rd li element)

```
<ul class="example-ul-class">
   <li class="example-li-class"><a href="https://wwww.example.com">EXAMPLE NAME</a></li>
   <li><i class="example-li-class">12 hours ago</time></li>
   <li><i class="example-li-class"> 170 votes</li>
   <li><i class="example-li-class">3 min read</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using something like the below but am getting the error found after the code

subtext = soup.select('.example-ul-class > li[2]')

print(subtext)

Error:

in selector_iter
raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector at position 29
line 1:
.example-ul-class > li[2]

**Again, the desired output would be to return just the string '170 votes'

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a CSS selector, try selecting using normal BS methods:

```
print(soup.find('ul',class_='example-ul-class').find_all('li')[2].text.strip())
```